# Error while reading excel sheet - special character in sheet name

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am reading data from excel sheet using excel oledb with C#.

Query is below :

```
"SELECT * FROM [Test$A6:IU6]"
```

Its working perfectly. But if I give the sheet name "Test+" then I am getting error.

Query is below:

```
"SELECT * FROM [Test+$A6:IU6]"
```

The error I am getting:

"The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'Test+$A6:IU6'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly."

Is there any way by which I can read the data from excel sheet which has special char in sheet name ?

Comment: This is working fine at my side, may be some other issue, can you put your code here..

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to read in all the worksheets then extract the names they do have. This will give you an indication of what the name above is known as internally when the special characters are included and you can adjust for that.

See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ce4bbe9c-7d13-44c5-a26c-4b84912a51f3/read-excel-file-without-worksheet-name?forum=vbgeneral